# Unexpected output in a java program

Tags: java

I have written the following java code where I am getting `0` for area of A triangle. What can be the reason for this erroneous output?

```
package methodoverrideoverload;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Figure_Area {
    int dima;
    int dimb;

    Figure_Area()
    {
    }

    Figure_Area(int i, int j)
    {
        dima=i;
        dimb=j;
    }

    void cal_area()
    {
        System.out.println("Area is undefined!!");
    }
}

class Figure_Area_Tri extends Figure_Area {

    Figure_Area_Tri(int i, int j)
    {
        super(i,j);
    }

    void cal_area()
    {
        System.out.println("The area of the Triangle is "+((1/2)*dima*dimb));
    }
}

class Figure_Area_Rec extends Figure_Area {

    Figure_Area_Rec(int i, int j)
    {
        super(i,j);
    }

    void cal_area()
    {
        System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is "+ dima*dimb);
    }
}

class Figure_Area_Cir extends Figure_Area {
    double pi=3.14;

    Figure_Area_Cir(int i)
    {
        super.dima=i;
    }

    void cal_area()
    {
        System.out.println("The area of the Circle is "+ (pi*dima*dima));
    }
}

class findArea {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("<<-MENU-->>");
        System.out.println("Enter the figure you want to know the area of->");
        System.out.println("Press 1 for Triangle");
        System.out.println("Press 2 for Rectangle");
        System.out.println("Press 3 for Circle");
        System.out.println("Press 4 to Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice->");

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch=sc.nextInt();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter Height->");
                int h=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Base->");
                int b=sc.nextInt();
                Figure_Area_Tri tri=new Figure_Area_Tri(h,b);
                tri.cal_area();
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter Length->");
                int len=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Breadth->");
                int bre=sc.nextInt();           
                Figure_Area_Rec rec=new Figure_Area_Rec(len,bre);
                rec.cal_area();
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter Radius->");
                int rad=sc.nextInt();
                Figure_Area_Cir cir=new Figure_Area_Cir(rad);
                cir.cal_area();
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Choice");
        }
    }
}
```

I have examined the code in debugging mode and found out the values of `dima` and `dimb` are set as the input value, but somehow the function for area is most likely unable to give the correct result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this integer equation output 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633314/why-does-this-integer-equation-output-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With integers variables java uses integer maths, for example

```
1/2==0
```

To solve this use double maths

```
1.0/2==0.5
```

<sup>1d would also work instead of 1.0</sup>

So in your case

```
(1.0/2)*dima*dimb
```

As long as one of the variables is a double then double maths applies (be careful when the equation contains multiple "parts", each part must have a double in it).

#### What won't help and why

Note just casting to double (`(double)(1/2)*dima*dimb`) won't solve the problem because the detail is already lost by the point of the cast to double, it goes as

```
(double)(1/2)*dima*dimb
(double)(0)*(dima*dimb)
(double)(0)
0.0
```

Comment: Starting with 1d or 1f instead of 1.0 would also be an option, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Compass Very true, 1.0 is just my personal style

Answer (score 0):

You are using 1/2 which equals 0

You need to use a double, so 1.0 / 2.0 = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Try using double or float for 1/2.

If you use integers it will be 0 as there is no such thing as 0.5 with integers.

You can write `1/2f` for example or `1/2d` or look at other answers :)