# Why does this integer equation output 0

Tags: java, math

I am new to Java, please help me with this:

```
System.out.println(3 * (4 / 5) * 6);
```

Why is the answer 0?

Comment: You could change it to a Double and get the decimal places, otherwise 4/5 = 0.8 which rounds to 0 for an Integer in Java. Try it yourself. System.out.println(4\5);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: In primary school you will have done integer division with remainders.  4 divided by 5 is 0 with 4 remaining.

Answer (score 8):

Its a simple `BODMAS` Expression Evaluation

Evaluation for (3 * (4 / 5) * 6) will be;

```
1. (4/5)=0
2. 3*0=0
3. 0*6=0
```

To avoid 0 answer you can modifiy expression as

```
1. (3 * (4.0 / 5.0) * 6) // return float value
2. (3*4*6)/5 //return integer value
3. (3 * (4/ 5.0) * 6)  // return float value
```

In these cases answer will be non-zero for this expression

Comment: Or to remain in integer do (3*4*6)/5 - will keep as much precision as possible without having to use floats or doubles.

Answer (score 3):

`(4 / 5)` is 0 because they are integer values and the result of 0,8 is rounded to 0. Do `(4f / 5F)`. Now the result will be like expected. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html This is a usefull link for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember BODMAS rule

first operation will be `divide` means `4/5` will be evaluated and it gives `0` (because 4 and 5 are integers and it gives 0) and anything multiplied with `0` gives `0`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are working with Integers, not floats. `4 / 5` is `0.8`, but an integer cannot store that number, so it is rounded down to `0`. Then the rest of the equation is multiplying numbers by zero, which will always result in `0`.

Turn the numbers into `3.0`, `4.0`, `5.0`, `6.0` to turn the equation into a float-based one.

With integers:

`3 * (4 / 5) * 6 = 0`

With floats:

`3.0 * (4.0 / 5.0) * 6.0 = 14.4`

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is this term:

```
(4 / 5)
```

Because both numbers are `int`, the result will be `int`. Integer arithmetic in java *truncates* the fractional part (it doesn't round), so the result will be zero (`0.8` will become `0`).

Answer (score 0):

You're using *integer division* (since **4** and **5** are *both int*):

```
  4 / 5 == 0 // 4/5 = 0 with remainder equals to 4: 0 * 5 + 4 == 4
```

that's why the whole formula

```
  3 * (4 / 5) * 6 == 0
```

If you want **4/5** treated as *floating point division* and so that it has a result of **0.8** you should use *floating point numbers* as well: **4.0** and **5.0**

```
  System.out.println(3 * (4.0 / 5.0) * 6); // <- 14.4
```

P.S. It's typical behaviour not only for Java, but for C, C++, C# as well

Answer (score 0):

Because 4/5 = 0 in your case << It is integer division
To fix this, you can rewrite your code as follow\

`System.out.println(3 * (4 /` **5.0**`) * 6);`

And the result will be

```
14.400000000000002
```